# Call Ruby method recursively regardless of it's name

Tags: ruby, recursion, substitution

How to make a method to call itself regardless of it's name so that if I want to rename it, I could do the change in one place?

Example:

```
class MyClass
    def my_method
        self.children.each do |child|
            child.my_method if child.kind_of?(MyClass) #Replace here 'my_method' to something
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you want dynamically declare a method you can use `define_method`, if you to dynamically call a method use `call`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `__method__` to get the symbol name of the currently executing method, and `send` to execute any method by name:

```
def foo
  send __method__
end
```

This will create a stack overflow in a jiffy if you don't have some rational conditional controlling the recursion, of course.

*Edit* — It looks like by “recursively” you mean that you want to call it on all instances of that class. This doesn't really provide you any flexibility for renaming the method, however. If those instances reassign the name of a method and `undef` the original, Ruby still can't find it — methods are looked up during the execution of the program.

Comment: Corey from Cary: the problem of any recursive method blowing the stack is not really central to the question, so it might be better to convert your example to a more conventional one, such as: `def foo(count); puts count; count += 1; send(__method__,count) if count < 10;
end`.